# string is reference type but why it work as a value type when it's assignment updated

Tags: c#, string

This is a simple code snippet, which make me a bit confuse:

```
string s1 = "abc";
string s2 = s1;
s2 = "123";
Debug.Log(s1 + ":" + s2);
```

**The debug result is abc:123**

So why s1 is not updated to 123 as **s1 and s2 contain same reference** and if one variable update it then, second will get updated automatically.

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: @un-lucky the title of the question is same but the question content is different.I have check it before

Comment: The fact that strings are immutable or not (or that they are a reference or a value type) are of no importance to this question. This question is about variables, not about their contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of the use of references.

s1 is a reference type but its content is a value. You could think all variables are value types, but the way the compiler handles them varies based on value or reference type.

```
    string s1 = "abc";
```

s1 is equal to the address where "abc" is stored, let's say 0x0000AAAA

```
    string s2 = s1;
```

s2 points to the same address as s1 hence, its value is the same as s1. Both have values 0x000AAAA

```
    s2 = "123";
```

Strings are immutable, meaning you cannot modify a string, anytime you assign a new value or a modification, you are creating a new string somewhere else in memory while the previous one gets ready for GC, if needed (not in our case actually). At that point, s1 still has value 0x0000AAAA while s2 has a new one 0X0000BBBB.

```
    Debug.Log(s1 + ":" + s2);
```

Since both points at different contents, they print different results.

It is only a reference type because the value contained in the variable is not meant to be used as is but is meant to send the pointer to an address location in memory where the actual object is stored.

Except if you use out/ref (the & in C++) then it is implied that the value of the variable is to be used (the address), most likely as a parameter.

Note that this behaviour is the same with any objects, not only string.

```
Dog dogA = new Dog();
Dog dogB = dogA;
dogA.name = "Wolfie"; // Affect both since we are dereferencing
dogA = new Dog(); // dogA is new object, dogB is still Wolfie
```

EDIT: OP required explanation on ref/out.

when you want to  change an object you would think of the following:

```
void ChangeObject(GameObject objParam)
{
   objParam = new GameObject("Eve");
}

void Start(){
    GameObject obj = new GameObject("Adam");
    ChangeObject(obj);
    Debug.Log(obj.name); // Adam...hold on should be Eve (??!!)
}
```

ChangeObject gets a GameObejct as parameter, the compiler copies the value contained in obj (00000AAAA) onto objParam, it makes a copy of it and both now have same value.

Within the method, objParam is given a new value and is no more related to the obj outside of the method. objParam is local to the method and is removed on completion (the game object is still in the scene but the reference is lost).

If you wish to change obj within the method:

```
void ChangeObject(ref GameObject objParam)
{
   objParam = new GameObject("Eve");
}

void Start(){
    GameObject obj = new GameObject("Adam");
    ChangeObject(ref obj);
    Debug.Log(obj.name); // Yeah it is Eve !!!
}
```

this time, it was not the value of obj that is passed but the address of obj. So obj may contain 0x0000AAAA but its own address is 0x0000AABB, then objParam's value is now 0x0000AABB and changing objParam means changing the value stored at 0x0000AABB.

out and ref works the same, only that out requires that a value is assigned within the method, while ref can leave the method without affect the given parameter.

Comment: can u deine it more 'Except if you use out/ref (the & in C++) then it is implied that the value of the variable is to be used (the address), most likely as a parameter.'

Answer (score 1):

String is Immutable. 
When you assign `string s1 = "abc"`, you are assigning new object reference created by string literal `abc` to the reference of s1.
So when  you  assign `s2 = "123";` ,  s2 will be referencing to new object created by string literal `"123"`.
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

By assigning a string literal to a String variable, You are actually instantiate a new string object and assigned to the existing one. ie,

if we declare and initialize `s1` like the following;

```
string s1 = "abc";
```

Actually what is happening is we are creating a new string object `abc` and assign to `s1` Which is similar to: [assuming `Foo` is a class];

```
Foo fooObj= new Foo();
fooObj= new Foo(); // this will be a new instant
```

One more point for clarification; `new Foo();` will creates an object internally and assign to `fooObj` we are not able to alter the value of `new Foo();` because it's internally created but we can deal with `fooObj`

Comment: nice way to answer but almost same thing said already by fafse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because *variables* are not *objects*. Variables are *references* to objects

When you do `s2 = "123"`, you are reassigning the ***reference the variable `s2` points to*** (and not the ***object it pointed to***), to a different object (an object of type `string` with the value `123`)

And yes, `string` is immutable (as others pointed), but that is not actually the culprit on this question. This happens with mutable and immutable types, and with value and reference types. The key differentiation is that you are modifying the reference (the memory address) a variable points to, you are not changing the contents of that memory address.

With a value type:

```
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = i1;
i2 = 2;
Debug.Log(i1.ToString() + ":" + i2.ToString());
```

Would log: `0:2`.

And with a reference type:

```
public class MyClass {
   private string _cont;
   public MyClass(string cont) { _cont = cont; }
   public override string ToString() { return _cont; }
}

MyClass c1 = new MyClass("abc");
MyClass c2 = c1;
c2 = new MyClass("123");
Debug.Log(c1.ToString() + ":" + c2.ToString());
```

Would also log `abc:123`

There are only two ways to change the actual contents of the memory address a variable points to in C#: one is using `unsafe` pointers (and they have their own syntax), and the other one is passing that variable as a `ref` or `out` parameter to a method (and that needs to be explicitly done).